# Not calling pci_register_driver()

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

What would be the consequences in kernel >= 2.6, if one does not call `pci_register_driver`, but retrieves `pci_dev` "manually" using  `pci_get_device`?

[LDD3 mentions this](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-12-sect-1) as "old style probing", but is it still safe to do this *instead of* calling `pci_register_driver`?

Answer (score 1):

Is it too late to answer this question?
For dynamically adding new vendor and device id to the driver you can use:

echo "vendor device subvendor subdevice class class_mask driver_data" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/{driver}/new_id

Answer (score 0):

If it was *old sytle* at LDD3 time, now is *obsolete style*. The `BUSTYPE_register_device` and `BUSTYPE_register_driver` functions are necessary in order to make the bus system properly work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what if realize vendor id and device id dynamically, in runtime - i.e can't prepare `pci_driver` in compile-time (as it contains `const struct pci_device_id *id_table`)? What is the up-to-date way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Honestly I never thought about this. But what is the advantage of a dynamically device/vendor id? You can add some device/vendor id in the `id_table` and change them at run time within this set

Comment: For example, if one gets them as a module parameter. You can't change them in `id_table`, as they are `const`.

Comment: `device_id` and `vendor_id` are hardware, so they are `const`. Your PCI card has its own `vendor_id` and `device_id`. On load it sends this parameter to the kernel; the kernel compares its PCI drivers' `id_table` with the card device/vendor id in order to load the correct driver.